# Turn all the character inside a file into lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

#filename: abc.txt
#file content: You picked the WRONG house, fool!

I want to read my file as all in the lower case. I tried using these code below but I got an error `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'lower'`

```
reader = open('abc.txt', 'r')
low = reader.lower()
for line in low:
    print(line)        
reader.close()
```

expected result: you picked the wrong house, fool!

Comment: Change this line `low = reader.lower()` to `low = reader.read().lower()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code as per your requirements. You missed read().
You can always use dir() function of any object to check what attributes it has.
for example:

```
print(dir(reader))

['_CHUNK_SIZE', '__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_checkClosed', '_checkReadable', '_checkSeekable', '_checkWritable', '_finalizing', 'buffer', 'close', 'closed', 'detach', 'encoding', 'errors', 'fileno', 'flush', 'isatty', 'line_buffering', 'mode', 'name', 'newlines', 'read', 'readable', 'readline', 'readlines', 'reconfigure', 'seek', 'seekable', 'tell', 'truncate', 'writable', 'write', 'write_through', 'writelines']


reader = open('abc.txt', 'r')
low = reader.read().lower()
for line in low:
    print(line, end = '')
reader.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`reader` does not store the file contents, you need to `read()` first:

```
text = open('abc.txt', 'r').read()
low = text.lower()
```

It may also be preferable to use `with`

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.read():
        print(line.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

```py
oldFileContent = open("file.txt", "r").read()
newFileContent = oldFileContent.lower()

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(newFileContent)
```

So what you forgot was to "read()" the file and then call "lower()" on the read file content.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with open(filename, 'r') as f` so that you don't have to close the file. Secondly, you cannot use files that way - you should iterate through them using a for loop: `for line in f`. Line itself is a string, which means that you can implement the `lower()` function with the `line`

```
with open('abc.text', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()  # getting rid of the '\n'
        line = line.lower()
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Turn all the character inside a file into lowercase*

For me it sounds like task for built-in `fileinput` module. Assuming `abc.txt` is `You picked the WRONG house, fool!` you can do:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('abc.txt', inplace=True):
    print(line.rstrip().lower())
```

Then `abc.txt` content become `you picked the wrong house, fool!`. Note that I used `inplace=True` to alter `abc.txt`, `fileinput` consume `print` so there is not output to terminal and I used `.rstrip()` as otherwise it would result in double newlines (from reading file and `print`). If you wish to know more about `fileinput` usage I suggest reading [this pymotw article](https://pymotw.com/3/fileinput/).